# In Javascript how do I set multiple variables equal to the same function?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to repeat this function but each time with different arguments. This is what I have

```
var pathOne = function(person,place) { *script* };
pathOne(hagrid,forest);
pathTwo(barty,seawalk);
```

and so on...

How do I set a bunch of them equal to the function at once?

Comment: What is the significance of such assignment when the internal logic of the function is same. You should rather choose a generic name for your method to avoid such things and increase readability. This will reduce the LOC as well :)

Comment: You are right I didn't need to even add new variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question directly in your title, this is a common way to assign multiple variables to the same value:

```
var foo = 
    bar =
    baz = function(person, place) { /* function body */ };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below:

```
var pathOne = function(person, place){ *script* },
    pathTwo = pathOne;
```